# Sorting strings with numbers in filenames with Golang

Tags: string, sorting, go, numbers

I'm trying to convert some old python code into Go lang. But i got stuck at sorting the files in a folder. Since the files are always `AMA1.txt`, `AMA2.txt` etc. In python source code i did this:

```
files=[]
for file in os.listdir(someDir):

    if file.endswith(".txt"):
     files.append(file) 

convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text 
alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)',key) ]

files.sort( key=alphanum_key )

for i in files:
    print (i)
```

I got so far, but missing the sorting :

```
func main() {
    dirname := "someDir"
    d, err := os.Open(dirname)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer d.Close()

    fi, err := d.Readdir(-1)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, fi := range fi {
        if fi.Mode().IsRegular() {
            fmt.Println(fi.Name())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Go has a [`sort` package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/). Construct a sortable name from a name with a non-negative integer suffix.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
)

// sortName returns a filename sort key with
// non-negative integer suffixes in numeric order.
// For example, amt, amt0, amt2, amt10, amt099, amt100, ...
func sortName(filename string) string {
    ext := filepath.Ext(filename)
    name := filename[:len(filename)-len(ext)]
    // split numeric suffix
    i := len(name) - 1
    for ; i >= 0; i-- {
        if '0' > name[i] || name[i] > '9' {
            break
        }
    }
    i++
    // string numeric suffix to uint64 bytes
    // empty string is zero, so integers are plus one
    b64 := make([]byte, 64/8)
    s64 := name[i:]
    if len(s64) > 0 {
        u64, err := strconv.ParseUint(s64, 10, 64)
        if err == nil {
            binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(b64, u64+1)
        }
    }
    // prefix + numeric-suffix + ext
    return name[:i] + string(b64) + ext
}

func main() {
    dirname := "someDir"
    d, err := os.Open(dirname)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer d.Close()
    fi, err := d.Readdir(-1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("\nUnsorted:")
    for _, fi := range fi {
        if fi.Mode().IsRegular() {
            fmt.Println(fi.Name())
        }
    }

    sort.Slice(
        fi,
        func(i, j int) bool {
            return sortName(fi[i].Name()) < sortName(fi[j].Name())
        },
    )

    fmt.Println("\nSorted:")
    for _, fi := range fi {
        if fi.Mode().IsRegular() {
            fmt.Println(fi.Name())
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Unsorted:
amt099.txt
amt.txt
amt2.txt
amt100.txt
amt10.txt
amt1.txt

Sorted:
amt.txt
amt1.txt
amt2.txt
amt10.txt
amt099.txt
amt100.txt
```

Comment: Brilliant that works like a charm. Quite a lot of code compared to python, but go´s simplicity in other fields still makes it my new weapon of choice. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Collect each item into a slice and then [use the `sort` package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) to sort them.  There are examples and explanation in the package docs.

In your case it may be easier to extract the numbers prior to sorting.  For that, [you might find `fmt.Sscanf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscanf) useful.